# Use pan and tilt control of my webcam in a more precise way

Tags: c++, windows, webcam, logitech

I have a Logitech PTZ Pro 2. We use it to record and stream church services. It has a fantastic 10x zoom. But using the zoom over a distance of 10m forces me to control the pan/tilt in an extreme accurate way.

My first try was to use `CameraControl_Pan` and `CameraControl_Tilt` of the camera control interface, but they are not implemented.

Currently I can control the pan and tilt in two ways:

*Method 1:* Either I can use the custom properties by Logitech to control the pan tilt movement. It is possible to control the motor by steps of -1 or -1 in x and y axis (using a Logitech defines KsProperty attribute).

*Method 2:* The other way is to use the camera control with `KsProperty` /  `KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_PAN_RELATIVE` and `KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_TILT_RELATIVE`.
But using this way I can start the motor and I can stop the motor. I need to sleep at least for 55-75msec between start and stop of the motion. When the time between start and stop is to small, nothing happens. And I want to make motion as small as possible. To make the delay between start and stop as accurate as possible I use to poll the `QueryPerformanceCounter`. (Sleep/SleepEx is not granular enough).

In fact the difference of method 1 and 2 that method 2 (using the motor control) is more accurate when I use a small time value between start and stop. But using a small timing I risk, that there is no movement at all, when pressing the bottom of my small camera control application.

Is there any known other (may be custom) property for the Logitech PTZ cameras that control the pan and tilt in a more accurate way? Or are there other properties that may be available to control pan and tilt of the PTZ Pro 2 camera, i missed?

Or is there a way (other property) to define how granular step of the PT motor?

Or is there any software that helps me to explore the endless number of properties of the camera interface?

**Edit 1:**
I tested more. My idea was to detect, when the motor really starts, in getting `KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_PAN_RELATIVE` or `KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_TILT_RELATIVE`. So I want to start the motion check the property when the motor is on and delay the movement from this point on. But this properties return always 1! So querying this property tells me: Motor is on!

**Edit 2:**
In the `IAMCameraControl` interface only `PAN_RELATIVE` and `TILT_RELATIVE` return a flag for manual (2) control when I use a Get call. All other return either automatic (1) or absolute (0).

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to the logitech API you're using?

Comment: I don't have access to the link currently. But you need to register yourself at Logitech... It isn't very useful and it is buggy AND it doesn't contain a real documentation. The most valuable thing is how to stare and access the PTZ positions. I come back with the information in the evening (GMT+1)

Comment: Afaik there is this link at the bottom: https://www.logitech.com/de-de/video-collaboration/partners/collaboration-program.html